# Check if the button has changed in Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, button

I'm trying to figure out how to get my Javascript code to check whether or not a button has been chosen. If it has, I would like to display the button's value.

I have the following HTML:

```
<li class="control-group">
        <label for="amount" class="control-label">Select an amount</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="btn-group radioButtons amountButtons" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                @if (Model.PresetValues.Count > 0){
                     foreach (int value in Model.PresetValues) {
                        <button type="button" data-value="@value" class="btn @(Model.chargeViewModel.ChargeAmount == value ? "active" : "")">$@value</button>
                     } 
                }                   
                <button type="button" data-value="other" class="btn toggleDiv toggleOnce" data-toggle-id="#manualAmount">Other</button>
            </div>               
            <input type="hidden" class="radioHidden validate required validateAmount" value="" id="amount" name="ChargeAmount">


        </div>
        <div class="controls hide resize" id="manualAmount">
            <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                <button class="btn minus" type="button"><i class="icon-minus"></i></button>
                <input class="span2 plusminus" data-max="100" data-min="10" data-increment="5" data-value="25" id="manualAmountInput" type="text" value="$25" disabled>
                <button class="btn plus" type="button"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Those are my two options for the button and I would like to edit the following span

```
<span class="help-block">Your card will automatically reload $<span id="autoAmount">0</span> when your balance is lower than your reload threshold.</span>
```

I have the following script which I was led to believe will change the value of the span as it is clicked, but I am having a difficult time connecting them together.

```
<script>
    javascript: void (document.getElementById("autoAmount").innerHTML = amount);
</script>
```

if anyone has any suggestions or ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on kyllo's answer a little bit...

First you would need to bind a click event to your button. You can set it as an onClick attribute:

```
<input type="button" onClick="captureAmount(e); return false;">
```

Including the 'e' inside captureAmount will pass the click event itself over to our function, which we can use to figure out which button was clicked (if you are using this function in more than one place).

You can also use jQuery if you've included that library, to attach the function to every button on the page at once.

```
$('input[type=button]').click(captureAmount(e));
```

Or, specify buttons with a particular class..

```
$('input.amountBtns').click(captureAmount(e));
```

And your function could look a little something like this:

```
function captureAmount(e){
  var clicked = e.target
  ,   clickedAmount = clicked.value
  ,   display = document.getElementById("autoAmount")
  ;

  display.innerHTML = clickedAmount;
}
```

Comment: Hey Relic, I've tried using the following, by adding  
`<button type="button" onClick="captureAmount(e); return false;" data-value="@value" class="btn @(Model.chargeViewModel.ChargeAmount == value ? "active" : "")">$@value</button>`

and also the same onClick method to input class ="span2 plusminus"

Comment: I also use the following script 
        $('input.amountButtons', 'input.plusminus').click(captureAmount(e));

        function captureAmount(e) {
            var clicked = e.target
            , clickedAmount = clicked.value
            , display = document.getElementById("autoAmount")
            ;

            document.getElementById("autoAmount").innerHTML = display.innerHTML = clickedAmount;
        }


doesnt work as i get the errors e is not defined, when clicking on a value in the first part, & onclick the manual value = received msg of type number, expected a string

Comment: If you are using the method "$('input.amountButtons', 'input.plusminus').click", you need to be sure you have the jQuery library included on your page. You also should not have both that, AND the onClick attribute (pick one OR the other). Also, 'input.amountButtons' is targeting the button container. Your click event should be bound only to the buttons themselves.

Comment: The variable 'clickedAmount' assumes the value you want to get from the button you clicked is the 'value' amount. If you're storing the value you want in a custom attribute like 'data-value', then that line should be changed to 'clickedAmount = clicked.getAttribute("data-value")

Comment: Oh okay, I have an issue with changing the following `<button type="button" data-value="@value" class="btn @(Model.chargeViewModel.ChargeAmount == value ? "active" : "")">$@value</button>` to an input which would be 

<input type="button" data-value="@value" class="btn @(Model.chargeViewModel.ChargeAmount == value ? "active" : "")">$@value as the last trailing $@value is not enclosed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the innerHTML of the autoAmount span to change when you click a button, then you would need to bind an onclick event to that button, and then when the onClick event fires, you would do `document.getElementById("autoAmount").innerHTML = amount.value`

for example, in the button declaration you can add 
`onclick="updateAmount()"`

and then inside the script tags you would declare a javascript function that is called by the onclick event:

```
    function updateAmount(){
        document.getElementById("autoAmount").innerHTML = document.getElementById("amount").value
    }
```

(Keep in mind that your "amount" input box is hidden, though.)

Comment: Hey kyllo thanks for the response! I do have a question before I try this out, how does it recognize the amount if I take it from the manualAmount part of my html? thats something that I haven't figure out yet..

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question: You are trying to populate <span id="autoAmount">0</span> with one of a list of PresetValues, unless the user enters a value in manualAmount, in which case manualAmount should override the PresetValues? Is that accurate?

Comment: To make the function a little more global, you could use onclick="updateAmount(e)", then inside the function select the object that was clicked using using e.target

Comment: @kyllo yes that is exactly what I'd like to do! :)

Comment: @relic180 so basically for each of the buttons set the onclick to updateAmount(e) and then within the javascript function call e.target?